# PHP code not reading correct post_type data in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to show some data with `post_type` set to `project` in my wordpress index.php, but despite setting `post_type` to `project` in my code, the default and usual wordpress posts with `post_type: post` are shown.

I've searched for a solution for a couple hours, but I didn't find anything useful from stackoverflow or google search.

This is my code:

```php
<?php
  $args1=array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'offset' => 0,
  'category' => '',
  'category_name' => '',
  'orderby' => 'post_date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'include' =>'',
  'exclude' => '',
  'meta_key' => '',
  'meta_value' => '',
  'post_type' => 'project',
  'post_mime_type' => '',
  'post_parent' => '',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'suppress_filters' =>true,
  );

  $query_mine=new wp_Query('$args1');

  while ($query_mine->have_posts()) {

    $query_mine->the_post();
 ?>


<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="more">
  <div class="item active">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
  <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" class="img-carousel">
  </div>
  </div>
  </a>
  <?php
} ?>
```

I expected posts to be of type `project`, but it shows posts of type `post`.

Comment: Are you sure your post type is called `project`? Also, remove all of those empty array keys from your query, you don't need them (e.g. remove `offset`, `category`, `category_name`...anything that doesn't have a value. You actually only need `posts_per_page` and `post_type`. All the others are default values). Also, capitalize `WP_Query()`.

Comment: @disinfor Thanks, my code is prettier now but it still doesn't show `project` posts. I can see those posts in my database using `phpmyadmin` having `post_type` set to `project`.

Comment: I just saw it: `$query_mine=new wp_Query('$args1');` Remove the single quotes from around `$args1`. It should be `$query_mine = new WP_Query( $args1 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo: you are passing a string instead of your array to `WP_Query()`. Remove the single quotes from `$args1` when passing to `WP_Query( $args1 )`.

```
<?php
  $args1 = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'post_type' => 'project',
  );

  $query_mine = new WP_Query( $args1 );

  if ( $query_mine->have_posts()) : while ( $query_mine->have_posts() ) : $query_mine->the_post();
 ?>


  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="more">
      <div class="item active">
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="" class="img-carousel">
        </div>
      </div>
  </a>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```